# No lxc-clone found on system

Tags: lxc

I see some tutorials on the Internet use `lxc-clone`. But on Void Linux (lxc 3.14) or compiling from sources, there is no lxc-clone to be seen.

Was it removed or is the a replacement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lxc-clone` has been deprecated, and replaced by `lxc-copy`.